# As of 2011, what hash algo is the most suitable for message digest?

Tags: hash, md5, digest, hash-collision

I'm a bit conflicted with an answer when I google for this, as these algos are constantly improving and new exploits are being found and new issues come up all the time... a lot of advice on what algo to use is simply old, or keeping ideas from an older time when they were the best way.

I want to be very clear here: I'm not talking about passwords. I'm talking about message digests, not cryptographic hashes.

I could go ahead and use md5 as my first inkling for message digest (it's right in the name), but then I remembered there's more collisions than more modern algos out there. But then, what makes these newer algos more suitable for the message digest of a file or short string?

So that's my question, what's the modern message digest algo that should be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From that perspective, depending on the amount of data you are working with, SHA1 should do fine - if you will be working with larger amounts of data, a SHA-2 algorithm, such as SHA-256 might be more suitable as the fear of collisions in SHA1 is rising due to a flaw in its algorithm, but it isn't extremely serious when working with smallish amounts of data.

MD5 has been shown to be too vulnerable to collisions, as there have been attacks on SSL certificates that used MD5 to create a forged SSL certificate, so I'd stay away from there. Also depending on your application, MD5 is not FIPS 140 compliant, if that is of any importance to you.

SHA1 is ideal over MD5 because it is safer as MD5 is risky to use, and SHA1 has better performance in most common circumstances than SHA-2. The SHA-2 algorithms are by no means slow - but it has an edge. However, SHA1 is slightly riskier because you've probably locked yourself into using it - if collisions start to be found, it might be hard for you to change, so it might be better to invest in a SHA-2 algorithm up-front. The penalty for using SHA-256 over SHA-1 is very little, depending on how you will be using the SHA algorithm. SHA-2 algorithms produce a much larger output than SHA1, but at the benefit of the reduced chances of a collision.

So which one is right? It depends on what you are looking for and what your use case it. Hopefully now you can make a decision.

Answer (score 2):

When in doubt, use [SHA-256](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2). The other SHA-2 functions are fine too; however, SHA-384 and SHA-512 may suffer from a non-negligible performance degradation on small (32-bit only) platforms. This *may* matter for some specific applications.

For non-security related usages (e.g. first pass of indexing in a hash table, or detection of accidental, non-malicious data alteration -- the kind of job where you could use a [CRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check)), consider [MD4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1320), a predecessor to MD5. MD4 is even more broken than MD5, but also simpler to implement (with shorter code) and faster (actually, it has been measured to be faster than CRC32 on some ARM platforms).